# trigger an api again once network goes off in RxSwift

Tags: rx-swift, uiactivityindicatorview, reachability

Here is my code below. I need to call api multiple times until internet signal is on.

```
 buttonAction.do(onNext: { [weak self] in
                        
                          self?.activity.startAnimating()
                        
                              apiManager.callApi()
                            
                                .do(onNext: { [weak self] in
                                    
                                    self?.activity.stopAnimating()
                                    
                                },onError: { [weak self ] error in
                                    
                                    if let error = error as? NoNetwork {
                                        self?.activity.stopAnimating(errorInfo:error,presentationStyle:.alert)

                                        // here alert will be appear. On click ok button, need to trigger the API() again
                                    }
                                })
                .subscribe().disposed(by:bag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you didn't say how you want to deal with any other type of error so the code below just ignores them... Remove the `filter` if you want to show the alert for all errors.

```
let error = PublishSubject<Error>()

let retry = error
    .filter { $0 is NoNetwork }
    .map { $0.localizedDescription }
    .flatMapFirst(presentScene(animated: true, scene: { message in
        UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            .scene { $0.connectOK() }
    }))
    .share()

Observable.merge(buttonAction, retry)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [activity] in
        activity.startAnimating()
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)

Observable.merge(buttonAction, retry)
    .flatMapFirst {
        apiManager.callApi()
            .catch { error.onNext($0); return .just(()) }
    }
    .subscribe(onNext: { [activity] in
        activity.stopAnimating()
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

The `presentScene` function comes from my [CLE library](https://cocoapods.org/pods/Cause-Logic-Effect). In this code `activity` is a standard `UIActivityIndicatorView` instead of whatever you are using.

Comment: Observable.merge(buttonAction, retry) is repeated twice. can we make it in one go?

Comment: You could do `let trigger = Observable.merge(buttonAction, retry)` and then use `trigger` in the two places, but that kind of "DRY in the small" is an unnecessary level of indirection that just obfuscates the code IMO.